# virtual env does not take environment python path

Tags: python-3.x, python-venv

I  have created a simple flask app and deployed it on ubuntu.

```
#!/var/www/myprojects/flask/test_env/bin/python

from flask import Flask,request
import os
import pickle
#import sklearn
import sys

app=Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/index')
def index():
    print(sys.executable)
    return 'hello world'


if __name__=='__main__':
      app.run()
```

The output that i get in my console is `/usr/bin/python3` . I want to run my code from the python in the virtual env.

Comment: How did you run your script? What command did you use?

Comment: This is deployed in Flask and I am trying to access it through apache

Comment: Was your virtualenv activated when running `flask run`?

Comment: I just tested and it's working well. Depends on the program you use for your virtualenv, the command should differ, but you have to activate it before running flask.
With `pipenv` for instance, I'm doing `FLASK_APP=hello.py pipenv run flask run` and the output is `/home/me/.local/virtualenvs/the_env/bin/python`.